# Cannot set namespace provider to false in Asp.net core project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper, asp.net-core

I have a folder in the project, but I don't want it to influence the namespace. Usually there is a namespace provider option in properties of the folder, but now I see only this:

[image]

It seems like some kind of a bug, but I am not sure what caused it... I think I was able to do it before in Asp.Net core projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is a bug in Visual Studio API for DNX projects

https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206009219-Namespace-Provider-not-appearing-in-properties